# Probability of selecting 2 queens and 1 king from a well shuffled deck of 52 cards.

Tags: probability

Four cards are selected at random from a well-shuffled deck of $52$ cards. Let the random variable $X$ denote the number of queens drawn and let the random variable $Y$ denote the number of kings drawn. Find $f_{xy}(2,1)$

$f_{xy}(2,1)$ is the probability that exactly two cards are queens and exactly one card is a king.

$f_{xy}(2,1) = \binom{4}{2}(\frac{4}{52})^{2}(1-\frac{4}{52})^2\binom{4}{1}(\frac{4}{52})^{1}(1-\frac{4}{52})^{4-1}$

So, $f_{xy}(2,1) = 0.0073$. **This answer is wrong.** Accepted answer is $0.0039$ What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from other things, your basic mistake is that you are trying to work out some figure for drawing with replacement  in a situation where cards are being drawn without replacement.

The correct figure for drawing two queens and one king in four cards

$= \Large\frac{\binom42\binom41\binom{44}1}{\binom{52}4} \approx 0.0039$

---

**Added**

Also, in the header, you are asking for the p.m.f (probability **mass function**) when you actually just want the **probability** of getting $2$ queens, $1$ king in $4$ cards.

Comment: The term **Joint pmf** in the title is indeed misleading and better be not used.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you forgot to compute the probability of the non-queen, non-king card, and then you tried to compute the probability that a card you already identified as a queen is not a king. Due to the structure, this is more of a combinatorics problem. You have 6 ways to choose queens, 4 ways to choose king, 44 ways to choose the last card. How many ways are there to choose 4 cards?